# How to solve this tricky system?

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to solve the system through

```
Reduce[y*Sin[x] ==Log[2, Abs[y*Sin[x]/(1 + 3*y)]] && (6*y^2 + 2*y)*(4^(Sin[x]^2) +
 4^(Cos[x]^2)) == 25*y^2 + 6*y + 1 && Abs[y] <= 1, {x, y}, Reals]
```

, but obtained no output during more than an hour. I am interested in its symbolic solution.

Comment: ContourPlot suggests that the only solution with $|y|<= 1$ is given by $x=\pi/2 + 2 n \pi, y=-1, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @KraZug: Can you elaborate your hint? The plot ContourPlot[{y*Sin[x] ==Log[2, Abs[y*Sin[x]/(1 + 3*y)]] , (6*y^2 + 2*y)*(4^(Sin[x]^2) + 4^(Cos[x]^2)) == 25*y^2 + 6*y + 1 },{x,-Pi,Pi},{y,-1,1}] is empty for me.

Comment: Copying that code you just put and putting spaces inbetween `y` and `Sin` gives me a plot. If you expand the $y$ plot range slightly you can see the curve that includes $y=-1$ which is missed otherwise. To be precise, ContourPlot[{y Sin[x] == 
   Log[2, Abs[
     y Sin[x]/(1 + 3*y)]], (6*y^2 + 2*y)*(4^(Sin[x]^2) + 
      4^(Cos[x]^2)) == 25*y^2 + 6*y + 1}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -3, 3}] shows the multiple intersections.]

Comment: @KraZug: Thank you, it works.  My fault consisted in work with assigned values of x and y.

Answer (score 3):

Not fully analytic but hopefully convincing.

Define:

```
eq1 = y*Sin[x] == Log[2, Abs[y*Sin[x]/(1 + 3*y)]]
eq2 = (6*y^2 + 2*y)*(4^(Sin[x]^2) + 4^(Cos[x]^2)) == 25*y^2 + 6*y + 1
```

which we are trying to solve for `-1 <= y <= 1, -Pi <= x <= Pi`.
In `eq2`, both the `x`-term and the rhs are always positive, therefore it must be:

```
Reduce[6*y^2 + 2*y > 0 && Abs[y] <= 1, y]
(* -1 <= y < -(1/3) || 0 < y <= 1 *)
```

One can check by inspection that `y==0` and `y==-1/3` are not solutions of `eq2`; that restricts `y` to be : `-1 <= y < -1/3 || 0 < y <= 1`.

Looking at the x-term only in `eq2`, one can see that it ranges in [4, 5] for any value of `x`. This gives a more stringent condition on `y`:

```
Reduce[{4 <= (25*y^2 + 6*y + 1)/(6*y^2 + 2*y) <= 5, -1 <= y < -1/3 || 0 < y <= 1}, y]
(* y == -1 || 1/5 <= y <= 1 *)
```

- `y==1`: solution mentioned by @KraZug

  ```
  Solve[eq1 /. y -> -1, x]
  (* {{x -> \[Pi]/2}} *)
  ```
- `1/5 <= y <= 1`:

  Plotting the quantities in `eq1` one can see that there is no solution:

[image: eq1]

Comment: You could make the first Reduce use $\geq0$, so you don't need to check the endpoints.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: Thank you for your answer. I don't think "Plotting the quantities in eq1 one can see that there is no solution" is math or/and Mathematica. Maybe, the Minimize command is more appropriate here, but the one fails for me as well as NMinimize.

Comment: @b.gatessucks: This is not a complete solution and many steps are made by hand with Mathematica help. Thank you anyway.